# Click on highlighted element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to perform a click using javascript.
I have this autocomplete textbox. 
[Autocompletebox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yfrtt.png)

When I click on it it shows up 3 options and I must select one (I am trying to select the second one).
[AutocompleteboxOptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDTjg.png)

I have the following code:

```
var myElement = document.evaluate("//*[@data-cerberus='blogv3_setup_subcategories_custom']//input", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;  
myElement.value = 'Repas'; 
myElement.click(); 
var myElement1 = document.evaluate("//li[@class='active-result highlighted']", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;  
myElement1.click();
```

The first part of the code works as expected.
But the second click is never performed.

Any ideia how to click on that highlighted item?

Thanks in advance.